What is the best way to provide data across tests in one test class in PyTest except fixtures?
I need to write tests, that send user and unit create HTTP requests and then tests that send requests to delete them and check that all went right. As I need to do it in test functions, I don't really know how to pass user/unit IDs to next tests that delete created entities by that IDs.
Here's how I wrote create tests:
class TestControlCenter:
    users_data = user_data_generator()
    params = [users_data[1], users_data[2]]
    param_ids = [data[0] for data in params]

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("users_data", params, ids=param_ids)
    def test_user_create_by_manager(self, manager_session_fixture, users_data):
        users_data = users_data
        director_methods = manager_session_fixture
        status_code = director_methods.send_user_create_request(users_data)[0]

        assert status_code == 200, "ERROR | Manager couldn't create user"

    def test_unit_create_by_manager(self, manager_session_fixture):
        director_methods = manager_session_fixture
        unit_name = unit_name_generator()
        status_code = director_methods.send_unit_create_request(unit_name, 2, 16)[0]

        assert status_code == 200, "ERROR | Manager couldn't create unit"

Function send_user/unit_create_request returns ID as [1] element, but as I don't know, how to pass IDs to delete tests, I don't use it here

tests are supposed to be independent, meaning it should be possible to execute them in any order or just a few of them and they should work the same. If you have one test setup the other, you break this principle.

Just  make your delete-test create its own data before deleting it.

@julaine, I should clean up test data, so I need to delete all the entities

each test should clean up after itself, deleting the entities it created. Then you don't need to pass IDs from one test to the other.
